# How to count word pairs and output the file

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $line = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

while ($line =~ /(\w+)\s(?=(\w+\b))/g) {
    print("$1 $2\n");
}
```

**So far this will output
The quick
quick brown
brown fox....

Is there a way to output a text file that also includes word count for example:
The quick: 3 (times of occurrence)
quick brown:2
brown fox:5...

Maybe we can use something like

```
$wordcount{$word} += 1;
```

but of course any plausible solutions are welcomed and thank you guys very much. P.S. apologies for the vague expression since I am a super beginner.

**

Comment: Well, why don't you try `$wordcount{$word} += 1;` and see if it works...? Try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%wordcount` to see the whole hash. In your case, I think I might do `$count{$1}{$2}++` for simplicity, or `$count{"$1 $2"}++`

Comment: How to print to a file: [perldoc -f open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open)

Comment: Don't need that `\b` (it's a "word boundary") since the preceding `\w+` (string of word-characters) stops matching precisely at a non-word character anyway

Answer (score 3):

You could use a hash that maps the word pair (key) to the number of occurrences (value).

Example:

```perl
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

my %paircount;
while ($line =~ /(\w+)\s+(?=(\w+\b))/g) {
    # put the word pair in the map and increase the count
    $paircount{"$1 $2"}++;
}

# print the result
while(my($key, $value) = each %paircount) {
    print "$key : $value time(s)\n";
}
```

Possible output:

```
fox jumps : 1 time(s)
lazy dog : 1 time(s)
over the : 1 time(s)
the lazy : 1 time(s)
brown fox : 1 time(s)
jumps over : 1 time(s)
quick brown : 1 time(s)
The quick : 1 time(s)
```

Comment: thank you guys for the helpful comments! I'll try to comprehend now!